# Combine dict comprehension with list comprehension to merge dict pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Given dictionary 'countries':

```
countries = [
{'country': 'Aruba', 'iso3': 'ABW'},
{'country': 'Afghanistan', 'iso3': 'AFG'},
{'country': 'Angola', 'iso3': 'AGO'}, 
{'country': 'Anguilla', 'iso3': 'AIA'},
{'country': 'Albania', 'iso3': 'ALB'},
{'country': 'Andorra', 'iso3': 'AND'}, 
{'country': 'United Arab Emirates', 'iso3': 'ARE'}, 
{'country': 'Argentina', 'iso3': 'ARG'}, 
{'country': 'Armenia', 'iso3': 'ARM'}, 
{'country': 'American Samoa', 'iso3': 'ASM'}
]
```

I want to have iso3 value as a key and country value as a value. Desired output:

```
[
{'ABW': 'Aruba'}, 
{'AFG': 'Afghanistan'}, 
{'AGO': 'Angola'}, 
{'AIA': 'Anguilla'}, 
{'ALB': 'Albania'}, 
{'AND': 'Andorra'}, 
{'ARE': 'United Arab Emirates'}, 
{'ARG': 'Argentina'}, 
{'ARM': 'Armenia'}, 
{'ASM': 'American Samoa'}
]
```

I have achieved it with:

```
iso3_map = []
for country in countries:
    data = {
        country['iso3']: country['country']
    }
    iso3_map.append(data)
```

But im wondering how to do it more elegant way in a list comprehension.
I tried some ways, the closest I got was:

```
[{v if k == 'iso3' else None: v if k == 'country' else None for k, v in country.items()} for country in countries]
```

But doesnt return desired output

Comment: `{country["iso3"]: country["country"] for country in countries}` should be sufficient; I don't think that outer list is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you your desired output.

```py
[{country['iso3']: country['country']} for country in countries]
```

Comment: Instead of going through window, choose door... simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
iso3_map = [{x['iso3']: x['country']}  for x in countries]
```

Output

```
[{'ABW': 'Aruba'}, 
{'AFG': 'Afghanistan'}, 
{'AGO': 'Angola'}, 
{'AIA': 'Anguilla'}, 
{'ALB': 'Albania'}, 
{'AND': 'Andorra'}, 
{'ARE': 'United Arab Emirates'}, 
{'ARG': 'Argentina'}, 
{'ARM': 'Armenia'}, 
{'ASM': 'American Samoa'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

For the data you have supplied you can just reference the `iso3` and `country` values in each input dict to make the key/value pair for each dict in the result:

```py
data = [{ ctry['iso3'] : ctry['country'] } for ctry in countries]
```

Output:

```py
[
 {'ABW': 'Aruba'},
 {'AFG': 'Afghanistan'},
 {'AGO': 'Angola'},
 {'AIA': 'Anguilla'},
 {'ALB': 'Albania'},
 {'AND': 'Andorra'},
 {'ARE': 'United Arab Emirates'},
 {'ARG': 'Argentina'},
 {'ARM': 'Armenia'},
 {'ASM': 'American Samoa'}
]
```